# Modifying feature maps in keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano, keras

The features maps can be obtained using:

```
from keras import backend as K
# with a Sequential model
get_3rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                  [model.layers[
                                  [model.layers[
                                  [model.layers[3].output])
layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([X])[
      layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([X])[
      layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([X])[0]
```

This is good for visualisation of the data. But, I also intend to modify the output for each layer and then fed this output back to the network. Can anyone suggest me how I can do the same?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of modification are you looking for? and by "fed .. back to the network" you intend to use it as a new input for the entire network, or simply to pass the modified feature maps to the next layer?

Comment: I want to pass the modified feature map to the next layer. I have a graph structure and thus want to pass the modified output from one node to the other.

Comment: I have deleted my previous answer as I apparently misunderstood your question. When you say you want to modify the feature map - do you mean the weights of the previous layer or the results of the previous layer?

Comment: I have to modify both i.e. weights and output. For weights I used model instance and fetched existing weights using `model.get_weights`, I modifíed them and then set it back using `model.set_weights`. But, there isnt any such method for setting modified outputs to the network. Thus, I assume a custom layer will be needed. This is for the forward pass. I also have to do the same for the backward pass, but for now I am just focusing on the forward pass.

Comment: I've restored my answer to show how to use the Lambda layer to modify the output of a previous layer. Note that for the lambda layer you don't need to worry about the backward pass as it handles things for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm restoring this answer with edits to reflect additional information.

Assuming you have a model similar to this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1000, input_dim=1000))
model.add(Dense(1000))
```

And you want to run a custom modification on the output of the first layer before passing it to the second layer you can use the [lambda layer](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) as so:

```
f = K.function(\* some function *\)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1000, input_dim=1000))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: f(x))
model.add(Dense(1000))
```

Comment: That means I should add a lambda layer as a sandwich layer between my existing layers? Sorry, I am still a novice in cnn thus clarifying.

Comment: Yes. If you have layer A and B and you want to use your custom modification of A's output and give it as an input for B you should sandwich the lambda between them.

Comment: Thanks again. If possible, Can you share any example which might help with this?

Comment: Also, for `get_activations = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()],
                                 [model.layers[in_layer_number].output])` I will need model object. However, if I want to use it in lambda layer, how can I get the model object as I will need to call compile method to get model object.

Comment: Thanks alot! I will try this in my graph network and then will let you know the results. So far I am convinced and thus marking this as an answer. Thanks again!

Comment: I used your answer and created a new graph node and a layer to do the conversion. However, now I am receiving an error while using the layer output tensor variable. I have posted the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719812/error-while-calling-eval-on-tensor-variable-in-keras

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do this once you can do something like this:

```
modified_layer_output = your_old_function([X]) * some_modification
get_final_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[3].input],
                                  [model.layers[-1].output])
result = get_final_layer_output(modified_layer_output)
```

You could also create a new model to learn on your modified layer output.

Edit:
You could do your write your own keras layer to do whatever you want with the input and pass it to the next layer like shown here (https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have a graph structure. I want to do it iteratively on each node ( modify output and feed it to next layer) during the forward pass.